# Problems displaying Image in FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

I am trying to display an image in PDF using FPDF.
The path is correct. But It fails. I don't know the error. as it just don't create the PDF file. But If comment the line, then It does. Below is the line to display image.

```
$this->Cell(100,100,$this->Image('http://wos.wegrindasphalt.com/images/captured_signature/signature_'.$jobheaderid.".png", $this->GetX(), $this->GetY(), 70,45,'PNG'),0,0,'L');
```

Note: The path is correct, I have checked it.

Comment: As always when trying to find out what error happend: take a look into your error log file. That is where you can actually _read_ what is the issue is instead having to _guess_.

Comment: You have checked it also through a php `file_get_contents()`? Maybe the server has several controls to avoid not-human downloads (it's a common routine). Check the error logs (Apache error logs, i think): it's mandatory if you want programming fine with php.

Comment: just using `Image()` and not inside the cell.